# Strtok returns wrong data

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

I have encountered a weird issue with `strtok()` and I was wondering if you could explain to me what is going wrong. This is just a test program to see if I can get the character `'/`` assigned to a variable so I can run some code later.

*(to be specific, my intention is to recognize when a user wants to run a terminal command, so to make sure it is one, I want to use `/` as first character so I can `system()` the remaining string)*

Anyhow, this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char msg[256];
fgets(msg,256,stdin);
char character[256];

character[0] = strtok(msg,"/");
printf("\n%c --> this is the output", character[0]);

return 0;
}
```

the results vary, `printf()` may print null, the letters `q`, `a` , the character `!` or an unrecognizable characters.

```
/test                                                                                                                                

� --> this is the output
```

Comment: Strange, your compiler did not warn you?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). `strtok()` returns a pointer, not a `char`.

> The `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` functions return a pointer to the next token, or `NULL` if there are no more tokens.

You cannot assign a pointer to a `char` variable.

That said, the code does not do what it is supposed to do. `strtok()` returns a pointer to the *next* token, it does not include the delimiter.

> Each call to `strtok()` returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token. This string does not include the delimiting byte. [...]

Instead, you may want to look at **[`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)**.